# What does the path get from the server by getRealPath () in jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts, relative-path

I am using **struts 1.3,jsp** for developing application.
I want to know what following code will return path from the server.

```
 path = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") +"images\\logos\\"+ formFile.getFileName();
```

What will be the path from the server.Can i use this path for showing image on the page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: getRealPath is deprecated. (compare: [Interface ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)). You should try this instead (since spec 2.1):

```
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
String realContextPath = context.getRealPath(request.getContextPath());
```

Earlier to this, it was highly depended on the server implementation. According to the spec it was allowed to return null if the application was deployed as a archived module (war, ear, etc.) I believe this never happened e.g. with WebLogic. It returned the path to the temp directory where the archives had been unpacked. So, to make a long answer short:

Your code will end up with something like this:

```
x:\your\path\on\drive\images\logos\somename.ext
```

It's not possible to use this as an image URL.

Comment: OP is not using `ServletRequest#getRealPath()`.