# Build File Path in Java Web Project

Tags: java, css, jsp

I am using the following code to dynamically add css files to my web project. However, when I write out the absolute path to the css file, it return something outside my web project. For example, for testing, I have added css/style.css to the cssAssets ArrayList. When I check the condition of `f.isFile()`, it writes out `home/*username*/css/styles.css` instead of the relative path from the index.jsp file to the css directory. It should be going to `workspace/projectName/WebContent/css/styles.css`. Any help is appreciated.

```
public String buildHead()
{
    htmlHead = new StringBuilder();
    htmlHead.append("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");
    htmlHead.append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
    htmlHead.append("<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"max-age=0\" />");
    htmlHead.append("<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\" />");
    htmlHead.append("<meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT\" />");
    htmlHead.append("<meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\" />");
    if (this.title.length() > 0)
        htmlHead.append("<title>" + this.title + "</title>");
    else
        htmlHead.append("<title>MMJ Ceo </title>");

    for (String css : this.cssAssets)
    {
        File f = new File(css);

        if (f.isFile())
        {
            htmlHead.append("<link rel='stylesheet' href=\"" + css + "\"/>");
        }
        else
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    for(String js : this.jsAssets)
    {
        File f = new File(js);
        if(f.isFile())
            htmlHead.append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + js + "'></script>");
    }
    htmlHead.append("</head>");
    return htmlHead.toString();
}
```

**Update**

This code snippet is from my Page class located in the projectName.src.com.projectName.view, the css files are located in projectName/WebContent/css/style.css, and it is called from projectName/WebContent/index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What IDE are you using?  It sounds like Eclipse, in which case, "Yes: you should put your css/ directory under "WebContent/" (just as your "index.jsp" is also under "WebContent/").

... BUT ....

The root path of your running servlet is *different* from the actual, physical path on your web server.  Look here:

- [What does the path get from the server by getRealPath () in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091491/what-does-the-path-get-from-the-server-by-getrealpath-in-jsp)
- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-function-servletcontext-getrealpath)

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am going to run a quick test with what you suggested.